# Script not working to add a value to list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to add a value to list by using text box, but it is not working.

```
<input type="text" value="" id="ip1" class="ip1" />
<input type="button" value="Add" class="bt1" id="bt1" />
<br/>
<select>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
</select>
```

And the script is:

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    var $txtVal = $('#ip1');
    $(".bt1").click(function () {
        var opt = $("#ip1").val();
        if ($txtVal.val()) {
            $('<option />', {
                text: $txtVal.val(),
                value: $txtVal.val()
            }).appendTo('select');
        }
    });
});
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Your code works: http://jsfiddle.net/133tmbsk/

Comment: any error in your browser console

Comment: no its not working in my localhost . !

Comment: 'It's not working' is never enough information. Have you checked the console for errors? Have you checked which line of the script is failing? Help us to help you.

Comment: where/how are you including jquery?

Comment: no. i used same code in "http://jsfiddle.net/" its working but its not working in my localhost

Comment: What are you getting in your console?

Comment: What error it show ?

Comment: do you even jquery bro?

Comment: Adding jQuery to Your Web Pages: `<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>`

Comment: @Mehmet Mert Yidiran maybe jquery is not loading from google on localhost for some reason? maybe better to download and connect it manualy for localhost tests?

Comment: within <script type="text/javascript"> tag of my header part @atmd

Comment: @mani can you share the complete page(front-end)?

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="text" value="" id="ip1" class="ip1" />
<input type="button" value="Add" class="bt1" id="bt1" />
    <br/>
   <select>
     <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
     <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    </select>


$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".bt1").click(function () {
        var opt = $("#ip1").val();
        if (opt != "" && opt != " "){
            opt = "<option value=" + opt + ">" + opt + "</option>";
            $("select").append(opt);
        }         
    });
});
```

p.s jsfidle http://jsfiddle.net/4ve443zv/1/

Comment: this will add options with empty value , why you removed OP if statement?

Comment: i'll just make quick test. but you right,  i'll add empty string check

Comment: " better not to use char such a '$' in variable name" Strongly disagree. if the variable holds a jquery object it makes perfect sense to prefix it with `$` such as `$txtVal = $('#ip1')` although that isnt a great variable name

Comment: `if (opt != "" && opt != " "){` could be shortened to `if (opt){`

Answer (score 1):

thanks for every one its working after Successfully adding this

```
<script type="text/javascript"        src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript">
```